# What is the precedence of FrameStyle, FrameTicksStyle, and LabelStyle? How to have a LabelStyle different from FrameStyle

Tags: plotting, graphics, options, style

From the documentation:

```
Plot[2 Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {x, y}, 
 PlotLabel -> 2 Sin[x], LabelStyle -> Orange]
```

[image]

But then add a frame style:

```
Plot[2 Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {x, y}, 
 PlotLabel -> 2 Sin[x], FrameStyle -> Green, LabelStyle -> Orange]
```

[image]

To me this is unexpected. I thought `FrameStyle` controlled the frame style not the frame tick or frame label style (if explicit options had been entered for `FrameTicksStyle` and `LabelStyle`).

It is possible to separate the styles of the frame and the frame ticks (via `FrameTicksStyle`). I'm assuming I am missing something **very** obvious here but how can a user give separate the styles of the frame and the frame labels?

i.e. How can I create a plot with a blue frame and red frame labels?

(I know I can use `Style` when entering frame labels but I am seeking an answer in terms of plotting options -- if one exists.)

Comment: From docs: "`FrameStyle` can be used together with `LabelStyle` and has higher priority", and "`FrameTicksStyle` can be used with `LabelStyle` and has higher priority", and "`FrameTicksStyle` can be used with `FrameStyle` and has higher priority". The "Properties and Relations" sections of the docs are quite enlightening in this regard.

Comment: @J.M. ...and yet despite stating that both `FrameTicksStyle` and `FrameStyle` have a higher priority than `LabelStyle`, the explicit examples show that `LabelStyle` has a higher priority than `FrameTicksStyle`. I therefore wouldn't consider this part of the documentation to be enlightening :)

Comment: Hmm, when I tried out `Plot[2 Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {x, y}, PlotLabel -> 2 Sin[x], FrameTicksStyle -> Green, LabelStyle -> Orange]`, the tick labels came out green, and the other labels became orange, as expected.

Comment: How are you defining higher priority? `FrameTicksStyle` supposed higher priority leaves labels unchanged whereas `FrameStyle`, also higher priority but it changes labels. If they are defined to have the same priority in relation to labels shouldn't they act the same?

Comment: Let me re: word my first comment in this thread. My understanding of higher priority is that e.g. the `FrameTickStyle` will style the ticks regardless of the setting for `LabelStyle` but the labels won't be converted to whatever the `FrameTickStyle` is. While this is what happens with `FrameTickStyle` it is not what happens with `FrameStyle`.

Comment: My understanding is that `FrameTicksStyle` affects both ticks and tick labels. Thus, in the case of `Plot[2 Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {x, y}, PlotLabel -> 2 Sin[x], FrameTicksStyle -> Green, FrameStyle -> Red, LabelStyle -> Brown]`, the ticks+tick labels are green, the frame and frame labels are red, and the plot label is brown.

Comment: Not according to the documentation: "FrameStyle affects frame, frame ticks, and frame tick labels". No mention of frame labels. While these get subsumed in the `FrameStyle` in the absence of an explicit `LabelStyle`, I cannot see anything in the documentation that explains why the frame labels are changing. The effect on the frame labels should be the same as when you introduce `FrameTickStyle`ing (IMO).

Comment: Hmm, yes. The docs certainly slipped there. I wonder...

Comment: To me this seems like wrong behaviour. Think about it: You can separate styling for ticks and labels but not for frames and labels. Why should developers have expected users to want labels to be styled the same as the frame without the flexibility of altering that? Unless they just decided that if users want to style labels then they should explicitly wrap `Style` around the labels???

Comment: Not pretty, but you can do something like `Plot[2 Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {x, y}, 
 PlotLabel -> 2 Sin[x], 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Green, FontColor -> Orange],
 FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[FontColor -> Black],
 LabelStyle -> Orange]` to have different styles for the frame labels, frame + ticks, and tick marks.

Comment: @Heike can you put that in an answer? It may not be pretty but is still easier than wrapping `Style` around all frame labels.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch I've added my comment as an answer

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As I mentioned in a comment, you can do something like this to have different styles for the frame, ticks, tick marks, plot label, and frame labels.

```
Plot[2 Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {x, y}, 
 PlotLabel -> 2 Sin[x], 
 FrameStyle -> Directive[Green, FontColor -> Orange], 
 FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[Yellow, FontColor -> Black], 
 LabelStyle -> Purple]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To style the text you can use other options as well such as `FontSize`, `FontFamily`, `FontWeight` etc., but the various options seem to inherit from each other, so setting for example `FontSize -> 20` in `LabelStyle` will also set the size of the tick labels so you would need to set the `FontSize` in `FrameTicksStyle` to compensate.

Also, setting `FontSize` in `LabelStyle` doesn't seem influence the size of the `PlotLabel`. To change this you can use the `BaseStyle` option.

Comment: +1 I forgot the `FontColor` option sooo many times

Answer (score 4):

"How can I create a plot with a blue frame and red frame labels?"

You could use `BaseStyle` instead of `FrameStyle`, however this also colours the x axis.

```
Plot[2 Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {x, y}, 
 PlotLabel -> 2 Sin[x], BaseStyle -> Blue, LabelStyle -> Red]
```

[image]

Comment: This then raises other issues when you want to set frame thickness and so on. So it doesn't really address the more general separation of label and frame style.